# Internet is not working

Tags: 16.04, networking, virtualbox, firefox, proxy

I am using Ubuntu 16.04.3 in VirtualBox and the internet is not working.
In the beginning when I was trying to use Firefox it was not working, but I went in the Connection Setting and changed from No proxy to Auto-detect proxy setting for this network and now it is working in the Firefox:
[image]

But in Terminal if I try to ping to google.com it is not working:
[image]

The Networking configuraiton in VirtualBox is as below:
[image]

Could someone help me?
Is there anything else that I could try?

Answer (score 0):

Try to change to the below configuration.

[image]

Comment: I tried, but it is still not working.